# s3.getObject().promise() never returns anything

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, promise

If use this code within a Lambda which complies with everything I read on stackoverflow and on the AWS SDK documentation.

However, it neither returns anything nor throws an error. The code is simply stuck on s3.getObject(params).promise() so the lambda function runs on a timeout, even after more then 30 seconds. The file i try to fetch is actually 25kb.

Any idea why this happens?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({httpOptions: {timeout: 3000}});    

async function getObject(bucket, objectKey) {
        try {
            const params = {
                Bucket: bucket,
                Key: objectKey
            }
            console.log("Trying to fetch " + objectKey + " from bucket " + bucket)
            const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise()
            console.log("Done loading image from S3")
            return data.Body.toString('utf-8')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error loading from S3")
            throw new Error(`Could not retrieve file from S3: ${e.message}`)
        }
    }
```

When testing the function, i receive the following timeout.

> START RequestId: 97782eac-019b-4d46-9e1e-3dc36ad87124 Version: $LATEST
>   2019-03-19T07:51:30.225Z    97782eac-019b-4d46-9e1e-3dc36ad87124    Trying to fetch public-images/low/ZARGES_41137_PROD_TECH_ST_LI.jpg from bucket zarges-pimdata-test
>   2019-03-19T07:51:54.979Z    97782eac-019b-4d46-9e1e-3dc36ad87124    error loading from S3
>   2019-03-19T07:51:54.981Z    97782eac-019b-4d46-9e1e-3dc36ad87124    {"errorMessage":"Could not retrieve file from S3: Connection timed out after 3000ms","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["getObject (/var/task/index.js:430:15)","","process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"]}
>   END RequestId: 97782eac-019b-4d46-9e1e-3dc36ad87124
>   REPORT RequestId: 97782eac-019b-4d46-9e1e-3dc36ad87124  Duration: 24876.90 ms
>   Billed Duration: 24900 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 120 MB

The image I am fetching is actually public available:
https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/zarges-pimdata-test/public-images/low/ZARGES_41137_PROD_TECH_ST_LI.jpg

Comment: I updated aboves code. I did a copy/paste mistake while making the code more readable for stackoverflow. Aboves code behaves exactly as described.

Answer (score 29):

```
const data = (await (s3.getObject(params).promise())).Body.toString('utf-8')
```

Comment: Everyone should know that after HOURS of trying to figure this out, this solution was the one that worked for me. Thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: It still doesn't appear to work for me. I used the exact same line, and added a `console.log({ data })` and it never gets hit. In addition, there's absolutely no information that can give me any hints.

Comment: @dsomel21 create a gist and post it here, i'll try to help.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi Thanks :) I actually created a SO post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744707/await-s3-getobjectparams-returns-object-but-adding-promise-does-not

Answer (score 4):

If your Lambda function is associated with a VPC it loses internet access which is required to access S3. However, instead of following the Lambda warning that says "Associate a NAT" etc, you can create an S3 endpoint in the VPC > Endpoints settings, and your Lambda function will work as expected, with no need to manually set up Internet access for your VPC.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

Answer (score 3):

Default timeout of AWS SDK is 120000 ms. If your lambda's timeout is shorter then that, you will never receive the actual error.

Either extend your AWS timeout

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({httpOptions: {timeout: 3000}});
```

or extend the timout of your lambda.

Comment: This combined with Tim's answer about the VPC endpoint was useful to me: if there's no endpoint, the AWS client just goes off and does nothing because it can't connect. It's important to note that the "timeout" mentioned in this comment is for the full request. It would be wise to set the connectTimeout as well, which is not set at all by default. By setting it to 2000, I was able to see my connection fail (rather than waiting for the full Lambda timeout). See also: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/

Answer (score 2):

This issue is definitely related to connection.

Check out your VPC settings as it is likely blocking the Lambda connection to the Internet (AWS managed services as S3 are accessible only via Internet).

Comment: Actually the code was like you suggested. I did a copy/paste error while making the code more readable for stackoverflow. My fault - sorry. However, the code suggested by you does not return anything too. I fixed it in aboves description.

Comment: The code is correct. The problem is probably somewhere else. Maybe in connection. Is your Lambda inside a VPN? Do you get this behavior only for S3? Can you make a simple HTTP call?

Comment: No VPN, but a VPC and VPC security group. But if it was connection or permission related, shouldn't it throw an error or something?

Comment: It depends on the connection, let's say the client set connection timeout for 5 minutes, your lambda dies in 3 minutes, then you get no error or response.

Comment: You're right. I did not have this in mind. I changed my code to use a timeout of 3000ms. As described [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/5#issuecomment-416579946) I still did not receive a timeout because of retries. I needed to extend the lamda timeout to about a minute to receive the actual S3 timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using localstack, make sure SSL is false and       s3ForcePathStyle is true.

That was my problem

```js
AWS.S3({endpoint: '0.0.0.0:4572', sslEnabled: false, s3ForcePathStyle:true})
```

More details [here](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/338#issuecomment-348226992)

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure you are providing your accessKeyId and secretAccessKey?  I was having timeouts **with no error message** until I added them to the config:

```
AWS.config.update({ signatureVersion: 'v4', region: "us-east-1", 
                          accessKeyId: secret.accessKeyID, 
                          secretAccessKey: secret.secretAccessKey });
```

Comment: when lambda runs on AWS they always have correct credentials