# s3.getObject never responds when using Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call aws  s3.getObject (v2) or .send (v3) within a Google Cloud Function and the request always times out. When developed, I used a simple node/express server locally to create/test then put code in the cloud function. Here are my two working versions using the express server

```
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
};
```

V3

```
const createParams = new GetObjectCommand(params);
const response = await client.send(createParams);
```

V2

```
const s3Asset = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
```

Both of these will return the correct file asked for which I am then either sending as Buffer or creating Zip when multiple files.

Once I put this in a Google Cloud Function, it will never return and time out. I ran a quick http.url() call to google.com and it returned a status code of 200, so I know it has internet access. And it has a VCP connector to allow all traffic. The env variables are set and accurate. What else am I missing?

Here is my Google Cloud Function

```
  const s3 = new S3Client({
    credentials: {
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_ID,
    },
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    correctClockSkew: true,
  });

  exports.downloadAssets = async (req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      console.log('Hit OPTIONS');
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
      res.status(204).send('');
    } else {
      console.log('***** Assets to download\n', req.body?.assets, '*****');
      try {
        if (req.body?.assets) {
          var params = {
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: key,
          };
          const s3Asset = await s3.getObject(params).promise(); <<---V2
          console.log('*** I have asset *** \n',s3Asset) <<<-- this line never hits
          res.send({ buffer: s3Asset.Body, name: 'nameOfFile', mimeType: s3Asset.ContentType });
        } else {
          return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No Assets Sent' });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error downloading assets: \n', e);
        res.status(400).json({ error: e.message });
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55228171/13130697) ?

Comment: I would second the comment above - oh, the joys of asynchronous Javascript programming...

Comment: After days of debugging, I needed to have a specific setting for the VPC connector: Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector. NOT Route all traffic through the VPC connector. All is now working as expected...

Answer (score 1):

Change your Cloud Function's egress setting to route only traffic destined to private IP ranges through your VPC connector.

When you create a VPC Serverless Connector, resources like App Engine, Cloud Run and in your case, Cloud Functions, can connect to resources inside a VPC like a VM.

Let's say you have 2 VMs with Internal IPs `10.128.0.2` & `10.128.0.3`. Then, making the CF [use the VPC Serverless Connector](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#route-egress-to-vpc) for egress traffic to internal resources, you can call those VMs using their internal IP's from your Functions code (When creating the function remember to use `Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector` so only the traffic to reach internal resources uses the VPC).